# Multiple accesses of a singleton object in many classes

Tags: c++, singleton

I have a struct that multiple classes can access and edit. So I created this struct's object as static in class and created a get method.
**In Class1.cpp:**

```
#include "Class1.h"

static MyStruct struct;

MyStruct* Class1::get_my_struct()
{
      return &struct;
}
```

I thought of creating this class`s object as a singleton to guarantee that this struct can be accessed through a single object.

**In Class2.cpp:**

```
#include "Class2.h"  //Class1.h file included in this file.

void Class2::log_value()
{

Class1& singleton_obj_cls1 = Class1::getObject(): //return singleton object

singleton_obj_cls1 .get_my_struct().tempr_val=log_temp_val(); //log this value of struct by class 2 method

}

void Class2::change_value()
 {

    Class1& singleton_obj_cls1 = Class1::getObject(): 

    //Do I have to get the singleton object for different methods even though they are in the same class? 
   //Can a singleton object get in one place in class and the whole class use it as a class member?
        
        singleton_obj_cls1 .get_my_struct().tempr_val=45;
        singleton_obj_cls1 .get_my_struct().x_val=66 ; 
    }
```

I have class 3 class that uses both class1 and class 2.By the way, I changed class2`constructor to a singleton.

**In Class3.cpp:**

```
 #include "Class3.h" //Both Class1.h and Class2.h file included in this file.

void Class3::calculate_value()
{
 Class1& singleton_obj_cls1 = Class1::getObject(): 

 Class2& singleton_obj_cls2 = Class2::getObject():


singleton_obj_cls2.log_value();  

singleton_obj_cls1.get_my_struct().pressure_value=300;


}
```

My third question is, Is there a better design method that you can fix instead of getting singleton objects in multiple places before using each struct or should I create the object once in the top class and give it as parameters to all 100 methods of perhaps 20 different classes that should have access to this struct?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Do I have to get the singleton object for different methods even though they are in the same class?
> 2. Can a singleton object get in one place in class and the whole class use it as a class member?

Use a member variable in your header file and initialize it in the constructor member initializer list:

Example **Class2.h**

```
#include "Class1.h"

class Class2 {

//...

private: // maybe public/protected to access from other classes
Class1& m_singleton_obj_cls1;

};
```

Example **Class2.cpp**

```
#include "Class2.h"

Class2::Class2()
: m_singleton_obj_cls1(Class1::getObject()) {
}

//...
```

Comment: By making class2's constructor private, I can create a singleton object from Class2 inside Class3, right?

Comment: Sure same way as with Class1. I dont know your whole project but in my opinion it seems that there should be a much better design possible. My time today is limited so maybe some other has a better approach to this. Maybe i'll come back to this tomorrow.